# How to convert numpy distribution to an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am using the function numpy.random.normal(0,0.1,20) to generate some numbers. Given below is the output I get from the function. The problem is I want these numbers to be in an array format.

[ 0.13500488  0.11023982  0.09908623 -0.01437589  0.00619559 -0.17200946
 -0.00501746  0.07422642  0.1226481  -0.01422786 -0.02986386 -0.02507335
 -0.12959589 -0.09346143 -0.01287027  0.02656667 -0.07538371 -0.10534301
 -0.02208811 -0.14634084]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `numpy.random.normal` does return a numpy `array` - did you want a python list instead?

Comment: Maybe Dictionary format?

Comment: Yes I want a comma seperated list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just putting a `list(...)` call around your call to `normal` will turn it into a regular Python list.

Comment: Note that `x.tolist()` is faster than `list(x)`; it takes about one third of the time on my machine. But it doesn't much matter: for an `ndarray` of 1e7 entries, both complete in under a second.